# How Can I Build A Login Module Using Navigation(Jetpack) with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I Want To Implement A Function Like This:

When I Have Logged In, Show This Fragment With "Tab:Me"
[Logged In Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFCx3.png)

When I Have To Log In, Show This Fragment With "Tab:Me"
[Not Logged In Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL0r0.png)

Now I Use BottomNavigationView Load Fragment Which In Navigation Graph(JetPack), But I Don't Known How To Load Different Fragment By One "Tab"

Answer (score 0):

I Got A Answer!!!

First Step: Add **item** In My BottomNavigationView's Menu Like This:
(add authorizationFragment)

```
//bottom_navigation_menu.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/indexFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_home"
        android:title="@string/index_act_string1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/sellingFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_selling"
        android:title="@string/index_act_string2" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/exploreFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_news"
        android:title="@string/index_act_string3" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/meFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_me"
        android:title="@string/index_act_string4" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/authorizationFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/bottom_me"
        android:title="@string/index_act_string4" />
</menu>
```

Second Step: Create A New Fragment "AuthorizationFragment" And Add This Fragment In My Navigation Graph, And Set AuthorizationFragment's destination id like "authorizationFragment"

Third Step: In My MainActivity Which Host Navigation Graph, Use Code Like This:

```
if(loginStatus == true){
    bottomNavigationView.menu.menu.findItem(R.id.authorizationFragment).isVisible = true
    bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.meFragment).isVisible = false
}else{
    bottomNavigationView.menu.menu.findItem(R.id.authorizationFragment).isVisible = false
    bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.meFragment).isVisible = true
}
```

It Work Very Good!!!